# createCriteria Hibernate Code

Tags: hibernate, generics

I was going through a code my friend had written.
But i couldn't understand what the below code does.

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public List<E> fetchAllEntities(Class type) {
    return getCurrentSession().createCriteria(type).list();
}
```

Thank you in Advance.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it can easily be answered by reading the Hibernate documentation.

Comment: It would return a list of `type` class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the name implies, this code fetches all instances of the `type` from the database